# Handling an event from an inherited class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events, inheritance

I create an object of an inherited class. One of its events is to fire on change in a list. I tried writing up an example, but I found it far easier to put down my logic. By "an event is raised", I mean `RaiseEvent`. This is also my first time with custom events, and inheritable classes.

1. Create Object of Inherited Class (**in its own thread**)
2. Inherited Class runs MyBase.New()
3. Base Class starts listening for incoming requests
4. If request is received and valid, an event from Base Class is raised which is handled by the Inherited Class (with this event a list might be modified)
5. If list is changed, an event from Inherited Class is raised and is handled by the GUI
6. Base Class returns to waiting for a new request

I'm trying to avoid editing the GUI from the inherited class. The problem is the event never fires (it ignores the RaiseEvent in Step 5, and the GUI never gets an event). Possibly the separate thread is an issue?

Example of Step 5:

```
            Private Sub RequestReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.RequestReceived
'RequestReceived is from the Base Class
            Dim requestType As String = sender
            If requestType = "Type1" Then
               RequestIsVariantOne(sender)
            Else Then
                'Handle other variants similarly
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub RequestIsVariantOne(ByVal sender As Object)
    'Conditional statements go here that determine whether or not to edit the list
    'The statements will exit the Sub if it the list should not be edited.
    'If Sub hasn't exited yet, now we edit the list.
            ThatList.Add(sender)
'ListChanged is from the Inherited class
    RaiseEvent ListChanged(ThatList, Nothing)
        End Sub
```

Comment: The concept about OOP (inheritance , event ) is NOT connected with multithread , it talks the ideas how the data-structure organized. As what i thought , it's wrong way to investigate your problem along the multithread issue. Would you mind post some codes to demonstrate how the step5 event raise?

Comment: So what you're saying is simply that my problem is not related to threading? Sure, I'll post something.

Comment: Having classes listen to their own event makes very little sense.  Use a virtual method instead, use the Overridable and Overrides keywords.

Comment: You'd call an event inherited its own event? I agree with what you're saying, but I didn't think an inherited event was its own event. I've never used virtual methods/Overrides before. I'll have to read about it first.

Comment: Ok, not true. I have used a virtual method before, namely overriding ToString (and I'm also doing it in this project). I'll take that example and apply it to this, as well as replace my events.

Comment: Replacing the RaiseEvents in my base class with virtual methods won't work. The only way I can execute these methods is by raising events. Otherwise, I'd have to make an instance of my inherited class (to access those methods), which isn't going to happen.

Comment: It is for sure that raising event from derived class thought handling event of base class is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim rT As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenerThread)
        rT.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListenerThread()
    r = New RequestListener()
    *r.Listen()*
End Sub
```

In asterisks, this was the key element. Originally, it was called from the inherited class' constructor. This meant there was never a return to the GUI, and my class level variable was never updated. Therefore, any references to `RequestListener` (specifically the Events) wouldn't trigger **because `RequestListener` is Nothing**. Calling it from the GUI solved the `r IS Nothing` issue.

I discovered this by creating a button to raise the event manually, but was greeted with `NullReferenceException`. Once I started my listener from my GUI, the method handling my custom event was fired. I assume this solves my problem, but will need to work a bit more.